# How can I access running docker container instead of Apache2 Ubuntu default page?

Tags: windows, docker, google-chrome, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a Docker Desktop on my Windows with a container running. How can I access running container under localhost from my browser?

What is happening now is that when using Chrome the [Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvFLO.png) pops up at the localhost address, while in Firefox I see the docker container response under localhost.

This is the command that I am using to start the docker container:

```
docker run -p 80:80 app-name
```

Comment: Can you provide dockerfile and the command you're using to start the container

Comment: I added the command to start the container.